# Testing the parameter of a sub-sample

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bootstrap

I have some survival data from which I compute the annual failure rates. The parameter in which I am interested is the mean failure rate.

Now I select certain subjects that have a given characteristic, so the sub-sample is not random. For example, I have very few subjects having the characteristic in the beginning and I have more and more subjects with time. I want to "prove" that the change in the mean failure is not statistically significant.

To do so I use bootstrapping. I select randomly sub-samples from the data having the same number of subjects per year as the original sub-sample and compute the mean failure rate.

Then, I can compute the a p-value using the bootstrap distribution and eventually reject or not the null hypothesis.

I have some questions regarding this procedure:

- is it reasonable?
- what would be the alternatives?
- what is in this case (bootstrapping) the difference between hypothesis testing and confidence intervals?

### **EDIT:**

Let me give an example of type data I have.

A number of N subjects are followed over the years. The population is not constant, each year some new subjects can be added or some subjects can be removed. The subjects can be in 3 states {"healthy","ill","dead"}. Obviously, "dead" is an absorbing state, but recovery is possible from "ill"ness. I am interested in the mean failure rate per state ("healthy","ill").

I estimate annual failure rates per state with a cohort approach: I compute the number of subjects that are in states "healthy" and "ill" at the beginning of each year and look which ones have died at the end of the year. The estimator is imposed, I do not want to change it for now. But advices are welcome!

Now, assume that I have 2 types of subjects: presence of a certain gene or not. I am interested in the effect of this gene on the mean failure rates. Due to selection of subjects, it happens that there are few subjects with the gene at the beginning of the study and more and more subjects with the years.

I want to test if the mean failure rates of the subjects with the gene are the same as the global ones. I have used bootstrapping to compute a p-value. Assuming that I have $h_t^w$ healthy and $i_t^w$ ill subjects with the gene at year t, I sample with replacement from $h_t$ (healthy) and $i_t$ (ill) subjects (with or without the gene) $h_t^w$ and $i_t^w$ subjects respectively and look how many have died.

Comment: I don't understand this sentence: "I have very few subjects having the characteristic in the beginning and I have more and more subjects with time."

Comment: As I do not yet understand your question I can't answer parts 1 and 2.  Regarding part 3, it is possible to do the hypothesis test by inverting a confidence intreval (i.e. reject H0 if and only if the hypothesized value is outside the interval).  However, for hypothesis testing centering based on assuming the null hypothesis is better and was recommedned by Hall and Wilson in their paper Hall, P. and Wilson, S. (1991) Two guidelines for bootstrap hypothesis testing.  Biometrics 47, 757-762.

Comment: @MichaelChernick The sentence means that e.g. first year I have only 5 subjects having the characteristic (compared with 100 for the global data), second year 6,..., last year 68 (compared with 143) etc. I was thinking that I cannot simply take random samples, so that I need to sample with the same number of subjects  as in the original sub-sample over the years, so that I have bootstrapped samples under the null...

Comment: Are you talking about new subjects each year or the cumulative number over several years?

Comment: @MichaelChernick new subjects each year.

Comment: Somewhere along the line you have to relate the characteristic to the failure rate and although you show how the actual subsamples increase from year to year you haven't shown us a formula for the expected rate of increase in the number of patients with the characteristic.  Need a lot more information to solve this.  What else do you know about the survival curve?

Comment: This just sounds like prospective sampling based on the predictor values. I'm not sure whether this is true in survival analysis (I'd imagine it is) but in the context of regular regression, sampling based on the predictor values can still be a valid thing to do, since you're trying to make inference about the conditional distribution of $Y|X=x$, which you can get can a handle on within the range of the $X$s sampled since the $X$s are conditioned on, not part of the randomness in the model.

Comment: I would like to help you with this problem and I probably could answer questions about the bootstrap but I still am having a hard time understanding what you are doing.  You talk about an anual failure rate and you want to see if there is a difference from year to year. If you think that the failure rate is constant then you should try to fit an exponential failure time distribution to the data and see if it fits well.  Since we are talking about subjects with a specific characterisitc it seems okay to me to do this considering that what you have is a conditional survival curve.

Comment: Do you have complete observations for the failure times or are they censored? In survival analysis you generally do not start the curve at a fixed time but rather at time since entry into the study or some other common point.  Is there any way that you can explain better what you are doing?

Comment: Let me add to this discussion: I think you are using the word subsample incorrectly here. I would refer to them as the exposed population, in the sense that they have the gene characteristic. Your intent is to compare them to the unexposed population. In order to make that comparison, you have sampled individuals with both characteristics. Subsamples refer to nested populations within the sampled population, in which analyses are performed or interventions or more invasive or expensive assessments are applied.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand how you're bootstrapping, but you're probably doing it wrong. Bootstrapping would entail simulating observations conditional on the outcome process, the censoring processes, and the distribution of covariates, of which joint estimation is impossible. Additionally, you have correlated data. Subjects which "weave" in and out of the study cannot be observed during their censored times. You may alternately be aggregating data and using a log linear model approach in which bootstrapping might be a sensible approach, but I still don't know how that would account for repeat observations.

Let me suggest a completely different strategy--

Your inference sounds very much like a motivating description for a proportional hazards model. By adjusting for the gene expression you're interested in, you can compute and compare risk sets of individuals averaged over instantaneous time and estimate a hazard ratio, which is an approximation of the risk ratio between those with and without the gene. By looking at "risk sets" at failure times, you can eliminate censored individuals from the denominator and have true apples-to-apples comparisons of instantaneous "at-risk" populations.

How many repeat illnesses does an average individual in this sample have as a proportion of the total illnesses? If there are only few, you may consider only the first such failure, or entering all failures as independent observations. If there are many such failures, you would want to use a frailty model.